# Cordova SQLite con app Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic, sqlite, cordova, ng-cordova

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que ocupo el plugin de Cordova Sqlite.

Me ocurre un problema en la plataforma Ios cuando el dispositivo no tiene internet, cada vez que entro a la aplicación esta deja de funcionar, en los logs no recibo absolutamente nada. Ningun error, solo deja de funcionar la aplicación.

Dentro de `ionicPlatform.ready` declaro :

```
var db = null;

if (ionic.Platform.isIOS() || ionic.Platform.isIPad()) {
    var db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({ name: 'mydb.db', location: 'default' });
} else {
    var db = window.openDatabase("mydb.db", '1.0', 'My DB', 1024 * 1024 * 100);
}

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ranking (ranking_id integer primary key, ranking_titulo text, ranking_anio text, ranking_categoria text, ranking_detalle text)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ranking_jugador (ranking_jugador_categoria text, ranking_jugador_ciudadNombre text, ranking_jugador_email text, ranking_jugador_fono text, ranking_jugador_foto text, ranking_jugador_id integer, ranking_jugador_nombre text, ranking_jugador_paisNombre text, ranking_jugador_posicion integer, ranking_jugador_puntaje integer, ranking_ranking_id integer)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS jugadores (apellidos text, categoria text, ciudad text, email text, fono text, foto text, id integer primary key, nombres text, pais text, rut text)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entrenadores (apellidos text, ciudad text, email text, fono text, foto text, id integer primary key, nombres text, pais text)")
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS avisos (id integer primary key, aviso_creador_id integer, aviso_creador_nombres text, aviso_creador_apellidos text, aviso_creador_foto text, aviso_creador_fono text, aviso_creador_email text ,aviso_descripcion text, aviso_fecha_publicacion text, aviso_moneda text, aviso_precio text, aviso_tipo integer, aviso_titulo text, aviso_visible integer, aviso_imagen_principal text, aviso_visto integer)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS avisos_imagen (id integer primary key, imagen_aviso text, imagen_aviso_id integer)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS noticias (id integer primary key, titulo text, descripcion text, imagen text, publicada integer, vigente integer, user_id integer, user_nombres text, user_apellidos text, fecha_publicacion text)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS torneos (torneo_id integer primary key, torneo_nombre text, torneo_descripcion text, torneo_inicio integer, torneo_termino integer, torneo_afiche text, torneo_coordinador_id integer, torneo_coordinador_nombres text, torneo_coordinador_apellidos text, torneo_coordinador_imagen text, dias integer, estado integer)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fechas (fecha_id integer primary key, fecha_id_torneo integer, fecha_nombre text, fecha_club_nombre text, fecha_valor_inscripcion integer, fecha_inscripcion_inicio text, fecha_inscripcion_termino text, fecha_inicio text, fecha_termino text, fecha_categorias text, fecha_afiche text, fecha_nombre_coordinador text, fecha_apellido_coordinador text, fecha_imagen_coordinador text, fecha_email_coordinador text, fecha_fono_coordinador text, fecha_pais_coordinador text, fecha_ciudad_coordinador text, fecha_dias_inscripcion integer, fecha_resultado_pdf text, fecha_programacion_pdf text)");
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categorias (nombre_categoria text, categoria_codigo text primary key, vigente int)");
```

Pero al volver a darle internet al dispositivo todo funciona sin ningun tipo de problema.

**EDICION**

Verifique logs y obtengo esto cuando no tengo conexión.

```
2017-04-04 11:33:26.875810 MyApp[479:44694] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 33] Initializing SQLitePlugin

2017-04-04 11:33:26.876087 MyApp[479:44694] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 44] Detected docs path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D1DF9229-D8EA-48C6-A50C-7E3BA5863484/Documents

2017-04-04 11:33:26.876206 MyApp[479:44694] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 48] Detected Library path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D1DF9229-D8EA-48C6-A50C-7E3BA5863484/Library

2017-04-04 11:33:26.876299 MyApp[479:44694] -[SQLitePlugin pluginInitialize] [Line 55] no cloud sync at path: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D1DF9229-D8EA-48C6-A50C-7E3BA5863484/Library/LocalDatabase

2017-04-04 11:33:26.876920 MyApp[479:44694] OPEN database: mydb.db

2017-04-04 11:33:26.877012 MyApp[479:44694] new transaction is waiting for open operation

2017-04-04 11:33:26.877092 MyApp[479:44694] new transaction is waiting for open operation

2017-04-04 11:33:26.877152 MyApp[479:44694] new transaction is waiting for open operation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al consultar a los desarrolladores del plugin :

[Issue](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage/issues/663)

El error y que aun no descubro porque, es que cada vez que manipule la base de datos, en cualquier controlador mi código debe estar dentro de un

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
});
```

El asunto es que esto era necesario solo cuando no habia conexion a internet. De todas maneras soluciono mi problema.